# root defaults to welcome to Nginx when using a "greedy" location

Tags: nginx

It seems like similar questions have been asked consistently on the site, but despite of browsing dozens of similar questions, none of the solutions seem to work for me.

When I go to mydomain.com, then nginx shows the default "welcome to nginx" page, however, when I visit `mydomain.com/whatever/blablabla/whatever` then Nginx sends the user to `index.php?q=$uri` which is the expected behavior.

So the problem only happens when visiting the actual root domain: `mydomain.com`.

This is my `default` file:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    location / {
        include /etc/nginx/include/php;
        index index.php;
        root /var/www/mydomain.com/current/web;
    }
        location ~ /(.*)/? {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$uri;
        }
}
```

Under that configuration, visiting `mydomain.com` defaults to "welcome to nginx" page, but `mydomain.com/whatever` is sent to `index.php` as expected.

When I tweak that to, something like:

```
        location ~ /^(.*)/?$ {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$uri;
        }
```

or

```
        location ~ /^.*/? {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$uri;
        }
```

then `mydomain.com` starts working again, but `mydomain.com/whatever` starts showing a 404 page. I've tried a bunch of different configurations, but none of the configurations I've tried seem to fully work as I expect.

Basically what I want is pass the whole URL to a front controller, to parse it and take actions depending on the contents of such URL.

If it helps, I want to mimic in Nginx this behavior from Apache:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php
```

I also have another virtual host:

```
server {
    listen 0.0.0.0:443;
    root /var/www/mydomain.com/current/web;
    index index.html index.php;

    fastcgi_param HTTPS on;
    include /etc/nginx/include/ssl;
    include /etc/nginx/include/php;
}
```

Comment: do you have other virtual hosts defined?

Comment: I can't tell what is the problem, I'd say you still have the `default` virtual host and somehow it catches your requests, check `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled` and `/etc/nginx/conf.d`

Comment: Also I suspect that it might be a cached page somehow, try `mydomain.com/?a` instead of just `mydomain.com`